# Error in Cpanel | 0: communication failure Show/Hide Details

Tags: cpanel

Need your help on this my Cpanel account seems to have an error thus whenever I try to edit a file after then when clicking on SAVE button it takes so long to respond and in the end following message displayed

**HTTP ERROR 0: communication failure Show/See Details**